# UIDatePicker still showing date with time in textfield - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uitextfield

[image]I want to set my textfield's input view into date picker and when date is selected i want to fill text field with date format only but there is something missing  and textfield is also showing time with date and i can not find it here is my code

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.dob setInputView:datePicker];
```

this is defined in viewDidLoad() method and datePicker is the instance variable of .m file. Then the following methods i applied outside viewDidLoad()

```
- (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
      [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM '/'dd'/'yyyy"];
      NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
      return formattedDate;
}

-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    datePicker = (UIDatePicker*)self.dob.inputView;
    self.dob.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",datePicker.date];

}
```

and one more problem sometimes it shows a blank grey box instead of datePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line
`self.dob.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",datePicker.date];`
With
`self.dob.text = [self formatDate:datePicker.date];`

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Is there any way to show month like nov/12/2016 i mean month not in number

Comment: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM/dd/yyyy"];`

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

```
  @property(nonatomic,strong)UIDatePicker *datePiker;
  @property(nonatomic,strong)UITextField *dobField;
```

now .m file
 in viewDidLoad()

```
 self.datePiker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 self.datePiker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
 self.datePiker.date = [NSDate date];
 [self.datePiker addTarget:self action:@selector(LabelChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.dobField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,30, DEVICE_SIZE.width-40, 30)];
self.dobField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.dobField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDefault;
self.dobField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;
self.dobField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.dobField.font=textFieldFont;
self.dobField.placeholder=@"Date of Birth";
self.dobField.inputView = self.datePiker;
```

and then

```
- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender{

NSString *myString = @"10/05/2001";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
NSDate *yourDate = [df dateFromString:myString];
NSLog(@"new date formate is %@",[df stringFromDate:yourDate]);
self.dobField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df  stringFromDate:self.datePiker.date]];
  }
```

its work for me try thes code hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

alter your update text field's implementation with below

```
-(void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)sender
{
    self.dob.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self formatDate:sender.date]];
}
```